# Section heading format with accessibility package

Tags: sectioning, accessibility, structure

I am using the accessibility.sty package with the tagged option and I am getting an error when I try to center my section headings.  http://www.babs.gmxhome.de/download/da_pdftex/accessibility.sty

As a basic example, I have a class file, testcls.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testcls}[2018/08/02 Test Class]

\LoadClass[letterpaper]{article}

\newcommand*{\makeStatement}{
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}%
    \section*{
       \centering Statement
    }
    Some text.
  \end{minipage}}
```

And a document

```
\documentclass[12pt]{testcls}

\usepackage[tagged]{accessibility}

\begin{document}
\makeStatement
\end{document}
```

Initially when I did this in my original document my error was about \equal{Document}{Section} which I narrowed to \closeUntilPDFStruct and feel it is probably something to do with not protecting something.  Unfortuneatly, I am not experienced to this extent and do not know how to proceed.

When I simplified my example, I got an error about \let\reserved@e\relax, and I cannot figure out where this is coming from either.

Comment: You are aware  that you won't get a valid pdf if paragraphs go over a page break as the package can't handle this?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Does that apply here?  There are only three words in the document.  Am I missing something?

Comment: No that's not the source of your problem. But if you want to tag a real document it doesn't make much sense to spent much time to debug a package that won't work anyway.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for the suggestion.  What about what I have here makes you think I might have this problem?  Section will not be more than one line.  Is it the minipage?  Is there a line of code that people typically include to prevent this?

Comment: I would suggest that you look at the tagpdf package. I really don't want to spent time on an old, unmaintained package that will never work correctly and patches a lot of internal commands.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks.  I was unaware of this package.